# how to change the label property outside of the python Tkinter class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter project, the main script (not a full program, to long) looks like this, label (led_A) is created inside a TK class,

```
 ....
 def fun_A:
      ...
      #need to hidden led_A 
      #**need to implement** led_A.forget() or .place()
 class home(tk.Tk)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Graph ")       
        self.geometry("1000x800")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        F=Graph
        frame=Graph(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(Graph)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

 class Graph(tk.frame):
       def __init__(self,parent,controller):
          ...
          photo = PhotoImage(file='1.jpg')
          led_A = label(self, image = photo)

 app = home()
 app.mainloop()
```

So I try to implement led_A.forget in fun_A, how could I do? I tried `global led_A` but main program could not recognize it. Thanks

Comment: `app.frame.led_A`, requires `self.frame = Graph(...`

Comment: You need to change `led_A` to instance variable `self.led_A`, then you can access it as `app.frames[Graph].led_A`.  But you need to fix the syntax issues of your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate an object you need a reference to the object. In this specific case, you need to make `led_A` an instance attribute so that you can reference it. You also need to add a method in your controller to give you access to the instance of `Graph`.

To make `led_A` an instance attribute:

```
class Graph(tk.frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        ...
        photo = PhotoImage(file='1.jpg')
        self.led_A = label(self, image = photo)
        ...
```

To add a method to the controller, do something like this:

```
class home(tk.Tk)
    ...
    def get_frame(self, frame_class):
        return self.frames[frame_class]
```

Ideally, `func_A` shouldn't know anything about how `Graph` is implemented since `func_A` isn't inside `Graph`. That means that you need to add a function to `Graph` which will add or remove the led.

```
class Graph(tk.frame):
    ...
    def turn_on_led(self):
        self.led_A.grid(...)
```

Finally, you need to modify `fun_A` to use this method to get a reference to the graph and call the function:

```
def fun_A():
    graph = app.get_frame(Graph)
    graph.turn_on_led()
```